# Django Pagination "Page not found"

Tags: python, django, pagination

I'm currently having issues with my Django pagination. I have a query set of 9 objects and am paginating one object to a page. So I should have 9 pages total.

Paginator is showing that I have 9 pages, but when I click the "next" page button my (Always on the last/last two pages) my url turns to: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/forum/1?page=7`

Then I get a 404 page not found error along with "Invalid page (7): That page contains no results"

Here is my class code:

```
class DirectoryClass(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "forum_directory.html"
    model = Directory
    paginate_by = 1

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DirectoryClass, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        directory = Directory.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['directory_id'])
        context['page'] = 'forum'
        context['name'] = directory.first().name
        context['user'] = self.request.user
        topic_set = directory.first().topic_set.all().order_by('-last_post')
        print(topic_set.all())
        paginator = Paginator(topic_set, self.paginate_by)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            topic_set = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            topic_set = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            topic_set = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        context['topics'] = topic_set
        context['page'] = page
        return context
```

Here is the HTML used to change the page:

```
<div style="width: 1240px; margin: auto; text-align: right;">
    {% if topics.has_other_pages %}
      <ul class="pagination forum-pagination">
        {% if topics.has_previous %}
          <li><a href="?page={{ topics.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in topics.paginator.page_range %}
          {% if topics.number == i %}
            <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
          {% else %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if topics.has_next %}
          <li><a href="?page={{ topics.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Here is the url

```
    path(r'/<int:directory_id>',views.DirectoryClass.as_view(), name='forum_directory'),
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you post your html too

Comment: Added the html and url!

Comment: perhaps [this snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10640/) will help you..

Comment: It’s within the page range though. I have 7 items and it’s showing all 7 pages on the template but as I scroll through I’m hitting all but one. Then when I hit the 7th page I get the empty objects error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DirectoryClass, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['page'] = 'forum'
        context['user'] = self.request.user

        return context

def get_queryset(self):
    directory = Directory.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['directory_id'])
    topics = directory.first().topic_set.all().order_by('-last_post')
    return topics
```

use this only in your ListView, as Django provides pagination to all the Class Based View

Comment: What is the limit that Django provides? I don't want a page with hundreds of results before it is paginated.

Comment: it will limit according to the paginate_by what you have mentioned at the beginnig, so django will paginate by 1 only

Comment: I just tried this, but it isn't working -.. It just fills the page with all the items within the query set without paginating

Comment: @Exorator we are getting closer -.. Now nothing shows. So it isn't giving me my query set.

Comment: Could it be because it doesn't have access to the arguments?

Comment: Your object(s) live in `{% for object in object_list %}`.

Comment: did you add the def before get_queryset?? i forgot to add it,

Comment: Yeah! I'm able to get the arguments and stuff to work -.. I added "print(topics) right before the return. For some reason I'm not getting the query set in my template though

Comment: try as @allcaps has mentioned in the template

Comment: Is there a way I can access my query set within get_context_data?

Comment: Also, my pagination code for showing what page I'm on isn't working anymore.

Comment: The paginator `topics.` > `page_obj.`. So `{% if page_obj.has_previous or page_obj.has_next %} ... `
`

Comment: In context data you can do: `self.get_queryset()`.