# Django search pagination error, page not found error each time I try to move to page 2

Tags: django, pagination

I'm popping up with an error on my comic book ecommerce application. It's a Django app. Basically, the search function isn't paginating properly, giving me a page not found error each time I try to move to page 2 and onwards. It works fine in my general products listing area though, where there is no q-based search.

It works fine when I paginate just the products section, adding in...

paginate_by = 6

...into the class ListView section...

...and adding this section into the view.html section...

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

...But, once I try to paginate the search function in the same way, it appears to paginate, but page 2 and onwards just gives me a page not found error...

http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?page=2
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?page=2
Raised by:  search.views.SearchProductView

....I think it has something to do with q, and the view.html section, but I'm not sure.

Any help would be much-appreciated.

Also, here's my view.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}



<!-- <div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div> -->




<!--the heading with the result of the name-->
<div class="row mb-3">
  {% if query %}
      <div class="col-12">
        Results for <b>{{ query }}</b>
        <hr/>
      </div>
      {% else %}
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8 mx-auto py-5">
        {% include 'search/snippets/search-form.html' %}
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <hr>
      </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>



<!--create a card/item for each comic-->
<div class="row">
  {% for obj in object_list %}
    <div class="col">
      {% include 'products/snippets/card.html' with instance=obj %}
      {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
    </div>
</div>
<!--or else if no item just create a blank row and column-->
<div class='row'><div class='col-12'><hr/></div>
  {% else %}
</div>



{% endif %}


{% endfor %}




{% endblock %}
```

And here's a snippet that works within the view.html (search-form.html)

```
<form method="GET" action='{% url "search:query" %}' class="form my-2 my-lg-0 search-form">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" name='q' aria-label="Search" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'>
      <span class='input-group-btn'>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

As well, here's my view.py backend:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from products.models import Product
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

class SearchProductView(ListView):
    #PROBLEM WITH PAGINATION IN THE SEarch function and view
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436649/django-pagination-page-not-found?rq=1
    #https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acOktTcTVEQ
    #https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-Pw7Le30qQ
    #https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/
    #paginate_by = 6

    template_name = "search/view.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchProductView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        method_dict = request.GET
        query = method_dict.get('q', None) #method_dict['q']
        if query is not None:
            return Product.objects.search(query).order_by('title')
        return Product.objects.filter(featured=True).order_by('title')
        '''
        __icontains = field contains this
        __iexact = field is exactly this

        '''
```

Finally, here are my urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .views import (
        SearchProductView
        )

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', SearchProductView.as_view(), name='query'),
]
```

Comment: Can you add your view, form and urls to the question?

Comment: Sure, Iain, I just added them to my original post. Thanks.